# Assign value specific to each thread in TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, automation, testng

I am working on Distributed execution on Appium. As a part of it i need to assign different values to different threads(parallel=methods). I am aware of giving values to Test using params, i want to know is there a way or a listener to assign specific values to each thread ? Say each thread dedicated to specific device value.

Eg: `

```
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

<test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="device1" value="deviceid"></parameter>
    <classes>

        <class name="LoginScenarios" />

    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test2">
    <parameter name="device1" value="deviceid"></parameter>

    <classes>

        <class name="Checkoutscenario" />

    </classes>
</test>
```

`

Problem :

In the above example each time i add new scenario i should add a separate test with some device id.

If i have only 2 devices and i have 10 scenarios assigning device id to tests will be challenging.

Tried Hashmaps in @BeforeMethod , but i am facing sync issues.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a DataProvider instead ? That should basically be invoked for every iteration of your Test Method no ?

Comment: If i use data provider , say for two device id's , the same test method(method annotated @test) will be executed twice for each device. But , i need to use one device id in one test method and other device id in other test..  when i keep parallel = methods in testng.xml i need each teat method should take different device id's.